# Insert timestamp into file_put_contents output

Tags: php, date, time

I'm not quite sure if this is possible as im new to PHP but im trying to insert the date in the format below into my output.txt before the actual line of text.

```
file_put_contents('output.txt', $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

The date format im trying to define is

```
date("d/m : H:i :", time())
```

BTW, I know the time format is weird, im using the space : to be followed by the data.

The goal outcome would be:

```
4/18 : 4:32 : String of text.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the questions?

```
$date = date("d/m : H:i :");
file_put_contents('output.txt', $date.$data.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

not programmatically but useful ( in **windows**)

Automatically insert timestamp everytime a file is opened:

```
1. Open notepad
2. On the first line of the file type this:
.LOG

3. Hit ENTER to insert one carriage return.
4. Save the file

Now… everytime you open the file in notepad, a timestamp will be inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

$date = date("d/m : H:i :");
file_put_contents('response.txt', $date . file_get_contents('php://input'),FILE_APPEND);

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

This will create a text log file into same dir with data append also print the current time

```
file_put_contents(__FILE__ . 'mms.txt', print_r($_POST, true) . Date('Y-m-d h:i:s') . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

**Output**

```
 Array
( 
)
2020-05-12 03:47:52
Array
(

)
2020-05-12 03:48:52
```